# Why SerialGC is faster than ParallelGC when data set is small?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

From the *selecting a collector* chapter in this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html#sthref28):

> If the application has a small data set (up to approximately 100 MB), then select the serial collector with the option -XX:+UseSerialGC.
>
> The serial collector uses a single thread to perform all garbage collection work, which makes it relatively efficient because there is no communication overhead between threads.

And I proceed some tests on this,

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 60000; count++) {
            map.put(count, new Object());
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }
}
```

With SerialGC:

```
-Xms5m -Xmx5m -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+PrintGC
```

The result is about 50 milliseconds.

With ParallelGC:

```
-Xms5m -Xmx5m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+PrintGC
```

The result is about 6000 miliseconds.

I know the communication between threads may take some time in ParallelGC, is there any other reason why SerialGC is much faster than ParallelGC in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

5MB heaps are essentially degenerate cases. With lots of tweaking the JVM can be made to work under such circumstances, but by default it is very easy to run into problems.

A 5MB *heap size* does not mean you get to allocate 5MB worth of objects because at any given time the young generation will be partially empty, in other words it eats into your memory budget.

Unless you have a good reason to use these memory limits, choose something larger, the defaults are chosen for more typical workloads and may simply not work well under those circumstances.

**Second**

Setting JVM arguments may also change other default arguments, so the arguments you're setting are not the only things that change.

To get a better picture you can compare the computed flags as follows:

```
diff -U 0 <(java -Xms5m -Xmx5m -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal) <(java -Xms5m -Xmx5m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Thread the other reason which I can think of is:

When serial garbage collection is running then nothing else can run at all (aka "stops the world"). That has a good point though: it keeps the amount of work spent on garbage collection to just about its bare minimum.

Almost any sort of parallel or concurrent garbage collection has to do a fair amount of extra work to ensure that all modifications to the heap appear atomic to the rest of the code. Instead of just stopping everything for a while, it has to stop just those things that depend on a particular change, and then for just long enough to carry out that specific change. It then lets that code start running again, gets to the next point that it's going to make a change, stops other pieces of code that depend on it, and so on.

Comment: With SerialGC,five times GC happened. With ParallelGC, there are very very many times GC, but seems no space could be reclaimed.

Comment: @Utsav both the serial and parallel collectors are StW collectors. CMS and G1 are concurrent (or mostly concurrent) collectors.

Answer (score 1):

(it started as comment but became too long) 
- Did you use jmh for your benchmark? 
- How many hw threads do you have on the machine?

If the JIT has managed to do work your whole loop will be a nop since the data isn't used anywhere.
Escape analysis might have stepped in too but I don't think so, the number of objects are too large, I would guess.
 In other words, I'm not certain that you are measuring what you think are measuring. It might be better to use a `System.gc`instead. While it's only a suggestion all collectors I know of obey the call.
Note also that the only difference between the serial collector and the parallel collector is that the parallel collector uses all available cpu to run while the serial only uses one. None of them are concurrent, they are both StW compacting collectors (for the old gen). (Note btw that all young gen collectors (except C4) are StW copying collectors).

I would suggest writing a bench mark using jmh instead but it's not obvious right now how to write a strict benchmark for this.
Another suggestion is to take a performance test system (if you have one) and running it with the difference collectors using the same scenario and analysing the gc log. Then you would get a meaningful comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm not using jmh or other performance test system. I'm pretty new to jvm as well as garbage collection. Now, I just need have a basic understanding on these stuff...